# USB/udev: udev rule runs, sets permissions correctly, still can't access USB device

Tags: linux, permissions, usb, udev

## Problem

udev rule that sets group of USB device to `usrp`, mode to `0660` used to work for allowing my user, which is in group `usrp`, to access the USB device. Not anymore.

## Platform

x86_64 Fedora 34 / stock fedora UHD 4.0.0.0  uhd-4.0.0.0-3.fc34.x86_64

## Hardware discovery

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:568b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2500:0020 Ettus Research LLC USRP B210
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The rule in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/10-usrp-uhd.rules seems to work well:

```
…
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2500", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0020", GROUP:="usrp" MODE:="0660", ENV{ID_SOFTWARE_RADIO}="1"
…
```

leading to

```
$sudo udevadm test /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
…
1-1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/10-usrp-uhd.rules:15 GROUP 1000
1-1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/10-usrp-uhd.rules:15 MODE 0660
1-1: Handling device node '/dev/bus/usb/001/009', devnum=c189:8
1-1: Setting permissions /dev/bus/usb/001/009, uid=0, gid=1000, mode=0660
…
```

confirmed by `ls -l`:

```
crw-rw----. 1 root usrp 189, 8 Nov  9 14:53 /dev/bus/usb/001/009
```

And I'm pretty sure I'm in `usrp`:

```
$ groups
marcus wheel libvirt usrp mockbuild
```

## Symptom

```
$ export UHD_IMAGES_DIR=/usr/share/uhd/images
$ uhd_usrp_probe
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 11.0.1 20210324 (Red Hat 11.0.1-0); Boost_107500; UHD_4.0.0.0
[ERROR] [USB] USB open failed: insufficient permissions.
See the application notes for your device.

Error: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for ----->
Empty Device Address
```

(but works as root)

## Further side info

- used to work pretty well
- no entries in /var/log/audit/audit.log

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue under Fedora 35 with another SDR and resolved it by adding the "OWNER" / username for device access:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTR{idProduct}=="xxxx", MODE="0660", OWNER="myUser"
```

Then, run

```shell
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
```

This command informs udev deamon to reload the newly added device rule and re-trigger service again without rebooting this system. And now it works without root privileges!